# standalone noun that refers to a person with a birth defect

Tags: word-request

Is there a one-word noun in English that refers to a person with a birth defect?

By "standalone noun" or "one-word noun" I mean a noun that is not a compound one (like "power of attorney", "due diligence", and so on).

I have found words like "deformity", "abnormality", "anomaly" -- nouns that refer to birth defects rather than to people who have them. While it may be possible to use those nouns in English to refer to people who have those defects, all English dictionaries that I have looked through (among which are Webster, Cambridge and Collins) say that their primary meaning is **a** defect, not a **person** with a defect. This was a kind of surprise to me because in my language there is such a noun (that primarily refers to a person).

Comment: https://kidshealth.org/en/parents/birth-defects.html If there were such a term, it would likely be found in a text like that. And there is no such thing as a standalone noun. Nouns are nouns.

Comment: Remember to always be respectful with your phrasing @brilliant. Some word choices may offend others

Comment: Birth defects can be very different and can affect physical, mental, digestive, urinary or other aspects of a person, so this is the reason why is no known official single-word term for them. There may be several offending words, though. And there may be single-word terms for specific disabilities. We can help a bit more if you reveal some context in which the word would be used.

Comment: brilliant - If you hover over the downvote button, you'll notice a tooltip that says, "This question shows no research effort." You may have done prior research (as you told Lambie), and you may have checked the dictionary (as you told JamesK), but you did not fold one iota of that research into [your question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/218536/1), which is why I have downvoted it.

Comment: @J.R. "which is why I have downvoted it" - Which is the only one thing that I have learned from your comment.   :)

Comment: You missed the main message, then. Lots of people complain about unexplained downvotes. I explained mine in hopes that your future questions would include the research that you have done, instead of just firing off a one-liner that leaves us scratching our heads, and leads to a protracted discussion in the comments. This could have been an exemplary question from the outset had you bothered to summarize your research when you asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Even when talking about people with medical problems that have *not* existed since birth, there are often times when nouns don't exist. Instead, we used adjectives.

For example, there is no noun for *somebody who is blind*.

This sentence is possible:

> He is **a** blind.

However, it doesn't mean that he is without sight. It would be using a different sense of the noun [*blind*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blind#h3):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** : a person who acts as a decoy or distraction

When talking about the lack of vision, we can only use the adjectival *blind* (or *sightless*):

> He is blind.
>   She is a blind person.

---

A few examples of using a noun to describe somebody with a medical problem are:

> He is a mute.
>   She is a diabetic.

But it's certainly not a given that there is a noun for every ailment. (I actually suspect it's less common for there to be actual nouns.)

---

The same would apply, by extension, to describe a person who has had a medical condition from birth. Where there is not always a noun for such a person in general, there is even less chance of there being a noun for a person with a condition from birth. In fact, I can't think of a real-world example.

Rather than using a noun, we use the adjective **congenital** to modify an existing noun, or the the adverb **congenitally** to modify an existing adjective.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of *congenital*:

> **1 a** : existing at or dating from birth
>   // *congenital* deafness

To refer back to earlier examples, we would then say:

> She is *congenitally* blind.
>   He is a *congenital* mute.

---

In terms of *fiction* and colloquial language, we could use the word **mutant**. This has been popularized in science fiction and comic books, even though it doesn't have common real-world use at this point when discussing humans.

We often, jokingly, will say *You must be a mutant!*, but we're using the word figuratively, and don't mean it in a literal sense.

The word [*mutant*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutant) simply means:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : of, relating to, or produced by mutation
>
> *mutation*
>   **3 a** : a relatively permanent change in hereditary material that involves either a change in chromosome structure or number (as in translocation, deletion, duplication, or polyploidy) or a change in the nucleotide sequence of a gene's codons (as in frameshift or missense errors) and that occurs either in germ cells or in somatic cells but with only those in germ cells being capable of perpetuation by sexual reproduction

However, I certainly wouldn't use *mutant* in the normal course of affairs to describe the common case of somebody with a congenital birth defect.

Also note that  a *mutant* wouldn't necessarily have a negative or a positive congenital condition or trait. Mutations can also produce enhancements and desirable results. (Mutations are essential to evolution. In one sense, it could be claimed that modern humans are *all* mutants, relative to our ancestors.)